# Parallel random number generators in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, statistics, probability, montecarlo

Is there an implementation of the Mersenne-Twister and Wichmann-Hill parallel random number generators in R? 
I'm using the `parallel` package, but it seems that there is just the implementation of the L'Ecuyer parallel random number generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default random number generator in R is Mersenne-Twister.  You can change between them using

```
setRNG('Wichmann-Hill')
setRNG('default')#or setRNG('Mersenne-Twister')
```

If you want to generate numbers in parallel, you can use the `foreach` package.

```
require(foreach)
require(doParallel)
c1 <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(c1)
generateRandom <- function(rng='default',n) {
  setRNG(rng)
  runif(n)
}
result = foreach(i = 1:2,rng = c('default','Wichmann-Hill'), .combine = 'c') %dopar%
  generateRandom(rng,1e7)
stopCluster(c1)
```

This example generates 20 million random numbers from a U(0,1) distribution, with each half using a different algorithm.